# Are the original cyanogen downloads for old devices still available?

Tags: cyanogenmod

I have 13 old galaxy tablets running android 3.0 that i would like to run cyanogen on.  All google links are dead.  they are SCH-i800 and i wouldn't bother but something has happened to play store so that it's not loading on all but one of the tablets.  It gives a weird redirect to a web browser page.  Also i was considering using them as wall remotes for home automation but the app i want to use requires at least android 4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the source listed below, there were backups made at archive.com of snapshots and nightly builds of CyanogenMod. There are many models, but I am not sure about yours.

> Snapshots: https://archive.org/details/cmarchive_snapshots OR https://archive.org/download/cmarchive_nighlies
>
> Nightlies: https://archive.org/details/cmarchive_nighlies OR https://archive.org/download/cmarchive_nighlies

Source: [Complete CM Snapshots and Nightlies archive (xpost from /r/android)](https://www.reddit.com/r/cyanogenmod/comments/5kas0h/complete_cm_snapshots_and_nightlies_archive_xpost/)